# Activeadmin: Collection not working on filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, activeadmin

I am working on activeadmin filters. I have one filter which is not working. The filter:

```
filter :role, as: :select, collection: Common::User::ROLES
```

The scoped collection:

```
def scoped_collection
  Common::User.where(role: Common::User::ROLES)
end
```

Roles are mentioned in the user.rb file:

```
ROLES = [ ADMIN, CUSTOMER, SYSTEM, LEAD]
```

But on using this filter I am getting the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass):
    1: insert_tag renderer_for(:index)
```

Do anyone have any idea why this filter is not working?

**EDIT:** I have noticed that the select filter with option equals is not working and the same filter with other options like contains, starts_with, ends_with is working.

Comment: Is role also an association on user?

Comment: Yes its an association.

Answer (score 0):

The filter seems to be expecting an ActiveRecord relation since it's an association.

You can perhaps use the code you have in scoped_collection in the filter, and then get rid of the scoped_collection?

```
filter :role, as: :select, collection: Common::User.where(role: Common::User::ROLES)
```

Comment: I am receiving the same error after I have made the suggested changes.

Answer (score 0):

Super late, but have you tried passing it as a proc?

```
filter :role, as: :select, collection: proc { Common::User::ROLES }
```